# How do I disable/remove popout button of PDF in an iframe?

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, toolbar

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e4G4Zj2sGxVULX_thHG0yiS4vJdOepE4/preview#toolbar=0" />
  </body>
</html>
```

[W3SCHOOLS EDITOR](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_get)

As shown in the above screen, I am trying to load a PDF from Google Drive into [IFRAME](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) and trying to hide the popout button as well as navigation panel of the PDF. I have already gone through couple of videos in youtube to hide the toolbars and navpans but no luck.

I have also referred this link to understand iframe properties which we can use but could not find any way to achieve. Everywhere suggesting `toolbar=0` but I am not understanding why it's not working in my case.

Comment: Don't know if it is intentional or not, but you may want to change the google drive file id in the iframe src. Unless you OK with sharing its content.

Comment: These documents should be accessible across the globe wherever internet is available. Please suggest what should I do?

Comment: The people whoever is rejecting, do you have any questions posted in stackoverflow these related? is there any other reasons behind the rejection?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that simple to know what to delete, but if you drill down about 6 fathoms you should find the class to remove

[image]

It did not autohide from me, I deleted it:

[image]

The major issue is since that is Google's licensed property (a condition of use you do not mess in there) it will return on a refresh.

[image]

To simply make it invisible try setting opacity to 0:

[image]

[image]